# Is it possible to launch a shortcut in current directory path?

Tags: windows, command-line, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, cmder

I am trying to launch a Command Line Tool named `cmder` in the current working directory e.g. `C:\Users\USERNAME\Downloads`.

**Important note:** I do not have Admin rights.

To achieve this I have created a windows shortcut, and used a Shortcut Key to launch it `Ctrl + Alt + T` and I set the Start in attribute to `%CD%` which is supposed to point to the current working directory path, but it will always launch `cmder` in the user home directory `C:\Users\USERNAME`. I have tried to change it to a different path, e.g. `C:\Users` and it will launch `cmder` in `C:\Users`, but this does not help me.

Shortcut Properties & cmder instance launched using this shortcut:
[image: Shortcut Properties & cmder instance launched using this shortcut]

Comment: Try leaving "start in" empty.  One other option is to use a script.  I myself use LNK files to launch all sorts of things.  If you add .LNK to your PATHEXT environment variable, you can even do this from the command line.  Yes a little more security risk.. but to me it is worth it.

Comment: Also.. when you say "the current working directory".. you mean the directory the explorer is showing you at the moment?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Yes, exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a method of using the Explorer's context-menu *Send to* to open
`cmder`, which doesn't need admin rights:

- Position to the *Send to* folder by either:

  - Pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and running `shell:sendto`, or
  - Position Explorer to the folder
    `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo`
- Create in this folder a file named `cmder.bat` that contains the
  following text (verify your path to `Cmder.exe`):

  ```
  cd "%*"
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\cmder\Cmder.exe"
  ```
- Now you can right-click on any folder and select
  *Send to > cmder.bat*.

Comment: This works, but I have to go to the parent folder every time I want to do this. Also I 'm not sure there is a way to bind this action to a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: It's not that easy to do without admin permissions. For the current folder you could adapt [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451668/bat-file-to-open-cmd-in-current-directory), where you will do *Send to* on any one file in the folder.

Comment: *You can just enter `cmd` into the address bar in Explorer and it starts up in that path.* - Will this work as well for `cmder` if I add it to my Environment Path Variables (which doesn't require ADMIN)?

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have just tried what I suggested in my previous comment, and it worked. Now I wish I could add this process to a keyboard shortcut :)